# Ember.js IF statement with OR conditional causing unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript

Seems a simple problem, but I just can't figure out why the following code simply won't work...

Regarding `gender1`:

If I use a computed property and try to check it against a few strings using the conditional OR, the result outputted into the label is always "male/female/other" even if the input gender1 contains one of those...

Regarding `gender2`:

However, if I do not use the conditional OR and test against only "male", everything works as expected...

**Template**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <label>:</label><br/><br/>
    <div>
        <label>Gender_not_working:</label>
        {{input value=gender1}}
        <label>{{verifyGender1}}</label>
    </div><br/>
    <div>
        <label>Gender_working:</label>
        {{input value=gender2}}
        <label>{{verifyGender2}}</label>
    </div><br/>
  </script>
```

**Controller**

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  gender1: "",
  gender2: "",
  verifyGender1: Ember.computed('gender1', function(){
    console.log(this.get('gender1').toLowerCase());
    if(this.get('gender1').toLowerCase() !== "male"||"female")
    {return "male/female/other";}
    else
    {return "MKay";}
  }),
  verifyGender2: Ember.computed('gender2', function(){
    console.log(this.get('gender2').toLowerCase());
    if(this.get('gender2').toLowerCase() !== "male")
    {return "male/female/other";}
    else
    {return "MKay";}
  }),
});
```

This issue also shows up on the [JS Bin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/timijiravo/edit?html,js,output) that I created...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a simple javascript mistake.
You can't compare 1 value to 2 "potential" values like you tried `(val1 !== val2 || val3)`. You can do `(val1 !== val2 && val1 !== val3)` or `([val2, val3].indexOf(val1) >= 0)` and probably a few other ways to achieve the same effect.